# Implementing Manually Coded Auto-Incrementing RowId/Using VACUUM in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have run into that timeless issue of wanting to have an auto-incrementing column (in SQLITE) that remains intact after a record is deleted.  I have run into a number of posts about this problem, but none of them explain exactly how to code your own column for this purpose. I need the numbers to be consecutive because I want to be able to display a record number for each item in a ListView which will also serve as a running total of how many records are in the db.

So far, I have been trying to use the VACUUM function because it's my understanding that it will reset the numbers once it's complete, and I thought I would run it every time a record is deleted, but nothing seems to happen when the code is run. I'm not getting any errors, but the VACUUM isn't happening as far as I can tell. Here's the code:

```
String sql = "VACUUM;" ;
    db.execSQL(sql,new String [] {sql});
```

Maybe nothing is happening because the coding is off? So I guess what I am getting at here is am I on the right track with trying to use VACUUM or should I go with manually setting up an auto-incrementing column? Either way, any advice is greatly appreciated!

Here's the fetch and display portion of the code:

```
 populateListViewFromDB();

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void populateListViewFromDB() {

    Cursor cursor = db.getAllRecords();

    //Allow activity to manage cursor lifetime

    startManagingCursor(cursor);


    //Setup mapping from cursor to view fields: 
    String [] fromFieldNames = new String []                
            {DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID,  DBAdapter.KEY_GENRE,  DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE, DBAdapter.KEY_PLATFORM, DBAdapter.KEY_DATE, DBAdapter.KEY_PRICE, DBAdapter.KEY_WHEREBOUGHT};

    int [] toViewIDs = new int []
            {R.id.RecordNumberEdit,     R.id.textView1,    R.id.textView2,      R.id.textView3,       R.id.textView4,       R.id.textView5,     R.id.textView6};


    //Create mapping from cursor to view fields
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.database_view_layout,
            cursor,         //Set of DB records 
            fromFieldNames, //DB field Names 
            toViewIDs       //View IDs in which to put info

            );

    //Set the adapter for the list view
    ListView listViewFromDB = (ListView) findViewById(R.id. listViewFromDB);
    listViewFromDB.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

I changed the VACCUUM code to the following since the original code was actually passing the query twice :

```
String sql = "VACUUM;" ;
db.execSQL(sql);
```

Still, though, nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: Well, passing the same command (`sql`) in twice is probably not the right way to be doing things. Have you consulted the documentation on that particular method?

Comment: can you post code of fetch and display data ?

Comment: I've read this page: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html. And I also checked this one out: http://lzone.de/How%20to%20Vacuum%20SQLite But I'm not sure I have the gist of how to properly implement it. It seems like it should be really simple, though. You mentioned that I was passing the command in twice...How would I alter the code to only do it once, then?

Comment: Post updated with additional code per Ketan's request.

Comment: Looking at this; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String) you only need to pass in the command once to the execSQL method and it should execute the command.

Comment: Post updated with revised code at bottom.

Comment: Primary keys should never change, and `VACUUM` will not change `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` columns. You should implement your own [CursorWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html)-derived cursor that computes the record number.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, CL. Any tips on how I might do that?